# PHP5.3 preg_match with Umlaute UTF-8-modifier

Tags: utf-8, preg-match, php-5.3, diacritics

the following command returns true on a PHP5.3.8 Lamp(Ubuntu 11.04)-Server, but false on a PHP5.3.2 Lamp(Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS)-Server.

```
<?php echo preg_match('/\w/u', 'ß'); ?>
```

I nearly changed all settings in the php.ini-file, but without success.
I changed the system locale to en_US.UTF-8 and made it the default locale for PHP. Additionally I tried the de_DE.UTF-8-locale.

In both cases I am using the default-packages provided by ubuntu.

Does anybody has another idea, what to change, without compiling any packages, so that PHP5.3.2 will also return true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PHP 5.3.2 uses PCRE 8.00 while PHP 5.3.8 uses PCRE 8.11.](http://php.net/pcre.installation) One [change in PCRE 8.10](http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt) was the addition of the [*PCRE_UCP* option](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> PCRE_UCP
>
> This option changes the way PCRE processes `\B`, `\b`, `\D`, `\d`, `\S`, `\s`,  `\W`,
>   `\w`,  and  some  of  the POSIX character classes. By default, only ASCII
>   characters are recognized, but if *PCRE_UCP* is set,  Unicode  properties
>   are  used instead to classify characters. More details are given in the
>   section on generic character types in the pcrepattern page. If you  set
>   *PCRE_UCP*,  matching  one of the items it affects takes much longer. The
>   option is available only if PCRE has been compiled with  Unicode  property support.

Unfortunately, you can’t trigger this option directly with a pattern modifier in PHP. It will be set by `u` together with *PCRE_UTF8* when available (PHP 5.3.4 and later).

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is not yet fully supported in php

The following code

```
$url='abc αβγ';
define('CONST_REGEX_SANITIZE_URL', '/[^\040\w\/\.\-\:]/u');
$invalid_url = preg_match(CONST_REGEX_SANITIZE_URL, $url) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo $invalid_url;
```

return 'false' with php > 5.3.10

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/DzAP7V
- http://codepad.viper-7.com/NR0ZD3

and 'true' with php < 5.3.3 (BTW the current Debian php version)

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/aJErJh